# How to select rows from an SQL table based on a column's value and add them to a list

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table with some data looking like this ( + a few more columns which I removed for simplicity)

```
internal_id   start_location end_location fleet_name Cars_n     departure_time 
832            value           value      XXX          [1,73,3]   10:15:17
832            value           value      XXX          [10,43,3]  13:15:17
83             value           value      XXX          [16,43,32] 15:15:17
85             value           value      XXX          [1,43,3]   12:15:17
```

Individual vehicles are based on the internal id.Each row represents a vehicle's journey, so, based on their id's some vehichles have more than one. I will be building a json with the journeys for each id, that's why I want to be able to sort them.

I want to sort the data in a list like so:
this_internal_id =[all rows containing its id]
inetrnal_ids=[[]]

I am thinking of something like:

```
    cursor = db.cursor(buffered=True)
    this_internal_id = ? How to define it?
    sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE internal_id = " + this_intenal_id 
    + ";" 
    print(sql)
    cursor.execute(sql)
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

Comment: there is no vehicle only cars_n, and which rdms are you using and wh is this tagged python?

Comment: @nbk, I amended the question and the tags. Each row represents a vehicle's journey, so, based on their id's some vehichles have more than one. I will be building a json with the journeys for each id, that's why I want to be able to sort them. I am sorry if the question is now clear.

Answer (score 1):

You have a code like this.

Here you must enter the internal id, which is tested if it is a number.

then will the query executed, you see that it is a prepared statement, to prevent sql injection

And then ever row is printed, in this case the first both rows, only to show you how it is done.

This runs all in a console, but frameworks like flask can give you a good gui for entering and showing the data

```
cursor = db.cursor(prepared=True)
this_internal_id = input("Please enter the internal_id and hit enter ")
sql = "SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE internal_id = %s;"   
try:
    val = int(this_internal_id)
    cursor.execute(sql,(this_internal_id,))
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        print("internal_id= ", row[0], ", startlocation= ", row[1]) 
except ValueError:
   print("That's not an int!")
finally:
    if db.is_connected():
        db.close()
        cursor.close()
```

Comment: Thank you. I am not sure I understand correctly your solution. I need to select all the rows with the same id for each id. So, should group rows like: for int id in internal ids:  append.rows to list. I can not prompt for an input.

Comment: run the code as it is, change the tablename, import mysql connector  and it will show all rows with the id you entered, i ran the code in visual studio, but you can run it in any console. in visual code you can make a breakpoit at any tome and run it line by line

Comment: @Thank you for taking off your time. However, this is not what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: so explain exactly what you want a json a list of all, basically you can construct everything when ou exchange the prinz line w

Comment: I want to be able to select all the rows with a certain internal id and to do this for add internal_ids, without explicitly typing the value of internal id. I want this to happen dynamically. I do not know how to define this_internal_id without entering its real value. Please excuse for not being able to explain myself clearly.

Comment: so why did your code have a where clause at all?

Comment: as I am still learning, I did not know how to do it properly

Comment: remove the where clause, so you get all internal_id in row[0] and the do in the loop what ever you need as i can't still don't understand what  you are trying